# Vectorization of 10^5 vectors

Tags: programming

I've got a question regarding vectorization.

I try to make it simple and as low on physics as possible.

So: I have 10^5 random generated vectors(just x and y component and z is set) with {[-5,5],[-5,5],-50} .

Now I have to recursive function that gives the approximated vector after 1000 Steps:

[image]

The problem is obvious: To do this recursiv function 1000 steps for 10^5 vectors is not possible.
But I got a hint in my task: I have to do a vectorization, which means that I define new vectors x,y,z who got all vectors in it:
Also define "updates" to these vectors:

[image: vector update]
So: my problem is not the physics part, but the programming part. Whatever I try it will still have to do the 10^5*1000 calculations.
Furthermore I dont really have an idea what vectorization really means.

Im really glad about every help.

Comment: did you already wrote some code? If yes, does it work for a smaller number of steps? It would be useful if you could add it to the question

Comment: Of course you will still have to do 1000*10^5 steps ;) The word vectorization in this case only means that you do each time step for all 10^5 vectors simultaneously, by putting all vectors into a `List`, thereby creating a matrix, and then operating on that matrix to compute the force, and from that computing the velocity (matrix) etc. If you use machine precision numbers and matrix multiplications with e.g. `Dot` to do the time steps, it should be fast.